# Adding elements from one numpy array to another numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Good morning,

I am trying to add elements from **one numpy array** to the other.

```
Jack = ["red", "blue", "yellow"]

Louise = ["orange", "green", "purple"]
```

When I do the following line, it adds the entire array instead of the elements.

```
Jack.append(Louise)
```

Out:

```
[["red", "blue", "yellow"],["orange", "green", "purple"]]
```

What I want to obtain in the end is:

```
["red", "blue", "yellow", "orange", "green", "purple]
```

Comment: `Jack.extend(Louise)`? and those are not numpy arrays, those are lists.

Comment: Yup. That did the trick. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in `numpy` you can use [`numy.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) with `axis=0` and if you want in `list` you can use `list_1 + list_2`.

```
Jack = np.array(["red", "blue", "yellow"])
Louise = np.array(["orange", "green", "purple"] )
out = np.concatenate((Jack, Louise), axis=0)
print(out)
# ['red' 'blue' 'yellow' 'orange' 'green' 'purple']
```

---

```
>>> Jack = ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
>>> Louise = ["orange", "green", "purple"] 
>>> Jack + Louise
['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange', 'green', 'purple']
```